# How to deploy the github page at another repo

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages

From the documentation of [GitHub Pages deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/), it seems possible to deploy an application at repo A to the github pages of another repo B. In my use case, I would like to deploy to an organization github pages `organization.github.io`. Since the organization github pages only accept files in the `master` branch, I would like to develop the app at another repo.

So in my development repo (let's call it `organization/app`), I have such `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
install:
  - npm install
script:
  - npm run lint
  - npm run build
deploy:
  provider: pages
  local-dir: dist
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  skip-cleanup: true
  keep-history: true
  repo: organization/organization.github.io
  target-branch: master
  on:
    branch: master
```

Even though the `repo` and `target-branch` has been specified, Travis CI still deploys all build files to `organization/app:gh-pages`, not`organization/organization.github.io:master`.

For a real word app, see this [development repo](https://github.com/SingularData/platform) and the [CI deployment log](https://travis-ci.org/SingularData/platform/jobs/375710318).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Check if you run a build with right commit hash.

By restarting a build you got an old commit set.

You either set a `flow` that triggers a build or you trigger a custom build.